# Vector Algebra. Help me to understand the solution

Tags: vectors

The problem is listed below. I am trying to understand the solution that is provided. Can you please explain me how they got the expression that I circled.

[image]

Comment: That is not correct.  The force  is $250\sqrt 3 N$  you must multiply the scalar $f$ by the magnitude of the vector.

Comment: @DougM Sorry, I don't quite understand. I am really bad with physics. Can you please explain this in detail? Thank you.

Comment: So, should we convert all four vectors to unit vectors, and find f from there?

Comment: It is not necessary to convert the position vectors to unit vectors, but it is an option if it is easier for you to think about it that way.